# looping over a column index in a data frame in r

Tags: r, loops

I have a data with two columns. [headsTails data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCowd.png). I want to create a loop such that each time the values of each row is entered into n1 and n2 respectively and the output(result2) is appended in a vector  powercal.
I

```
powercal <- c()

for (i in seq_along(headsTails)){

  result2 <- pwr.2p2n.test(h=0.3, n1=headsTails[i,i], n2=headsTails[i,(i+1)], sig.level = 0.05,power = NULL, alternative = "greater")

  powercal <- append(result2$power, powercal)
 }
```

Comment: `c(powercal, result2$power)` maybe? Note that growing a vector like this could be really slow for large `n`. It's best to create `powercal` with the final length if you now it in advance. Or better vectorize the whole process.

Comment: In your question you don't say what's your problem anyway. You should make it more clear possibly.

Comment: How about `for (i in 1:nrow(headTails))` and then subset it using `[i, 1]` and `[i, 2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will solve your problem:

```
powercal <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(headsTails)), function(i){
  pwr.2p2n.test(h=0.3, n1=headsTails[i,1], n2=headsTails[i,2], 
                sig.level = 0.05,power = NULL, alternative = "greater")
})
```

First: Using loops to accumulate values in a vector is never a good idea in R. Either you create a dummy vector of the desired output length and then replace each value, or better still use an apply function as here

Secondly: the code in your loop would increment the column number as well in each iteration (`n1=headsTails[i, i], n2=headsTails[i, (i+1)]`). Your dataframe has two columns, and you only need to increment the rownumber. I fixed that in my code.